# htaccess with multiple pages with same parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a problem rewrite rule. Please someone help me. my htaccess code is

```
    RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /sandbox/all_deals.php?city_id=$1&city_name=$2&cat_id=$3&cat_name=$4&deal_shop_id=$5&deal_shop_name=$6 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /sandbox/all_deals.php?city_id=$1&city_name=$2&cat_id=$3&cat_name=$4 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/(.*)/
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/ /sandbox/all_deals.php?city_id=$1&city_name=$2 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/
RewriteRule (.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*)/ /sandbox/index.php?p=deals&city_name=$1&shop_name=$2&cat_name=$3&dealname=$4&id=$5
```

i wants to show like following format

```
 1) www.domain.com/sandbox/city-name/shop-name/cat-name/
 2) www.domain.com/sandbox/city-name/shop-name/ 
 3) www.domain.com/sandbox/city-name/
 4) www.domain.com/sandbox/city-name/shop-name/cat-name/deal_name/
```

In my coding first 3 points in filename all_deals.php  and last one in index.php. when i use above htaccess my code conflicts it always redirects to the all_deals.php file.

How i will fix these issue. Help me. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your .* is greedy and `/` matches your greedy regexp.
You must use lazy regexp instead. You need to add `?` at the end of every regexp:

```
(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*?)/
```